# make the following matlab code faster

Tags: matlab

```
function c foo(a, b)
     for ii = [1 3 4 5]
          c = a(:,ii) +  b(:,ii);
     end
return
```

Can someone explain what this is doing? Is it adding column 1 of `a` with column 1 of `b`, then same thing for columns 3,4,5?  Should it be `c+=` ? Otherwise it's just overriding the last sum.  I'm not too familiar with matlab, does this code make any sense?  Can anyone see any ways to make this faster?

Answer (score 2):

If the code does what is supposed to do (yes, it does overwrite previous results, and returns only the last sum) the the fastest way to do this is:

```
function c foo(a, b)
         c = a(:,5) + b(:,5)
end
```

If it's supposed to add the columns and "join" them one next to another, one may use the indexing directly:

```
function c foo(a, b)
         ix = [1 3 4 5];
         c  = a(:,ix) + b(:,ix);
end
```